# Using same docker image in multiple agents during parallel build

Tags: docker, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to cut down on a build time by running some of my stages in `parallel`.
Currently my `Jenkinsfile` looks like this:

```
String NODE_DOCKER_IMAGE = 'company-docker.com:11452/digital-help/node-12-react:latest'

pipeline {
    agent {
        node {
            label 'centos'
        }
    }

    triggers { cron('H 1 * * *') }
    
    stages {
        stage('Prepare') {
            ...
        }

        stage('Install') {
            when {
                beforeAgent true
                not { triggeredBy 'TimerTrigger' }
                not { expression { isSkipCi } }
                not { expression { isReleaseDeployment } }
            }

            agent {
                docker {
                    reuseNode true
                    image NODE_DOCKER_IMAGE
                    args '-u root'
                }
            }

            steps {
                sh 'git clean -dxff'
                sh 'npm ci  --unsafe-perm'
            }
        }

        stage('Unit') {
            when {
                beforeAgent true
                not { triggeredBy 'TimerTrigger' }
                not { expression { isSkipCi } }
                not { expression { isReleaseDeployment } }
            }

            agent {
                docker {
                    reuseNode true
                    image NODE_DOCKER_IMAGE
                    args '-u root'
                }
            }

            steps {
                sh 'npm run test:unit'
            }

            post {
                success {
                    step([$class: 'CoberturaPublisher', coberturaReportFile: 'coverage/jest/cobertura-coverage.xml'])
                }
            }
        }

        stage('Integration') {
            when {
                beforeAgent true
                not { triggeredBy 'TimerTrigger' }
                not { expression { isSkipCi } }
                not { expression { isReleaseDeployment } }
            }

            agent {
                docker {
                    reuseNode true
                    image NODE_DOCKER_IMAGE
                    args '-u root'
                }
            }

            steps {
                sh 'npm run test:integration'
            }
        }

        stage('Artifact') {
            when {
                beforeAgent true
                not { triggeredBy 'TimerTrigger'}
                not { expression { isSkipCi } }
            }

            agent {
                docker {
                    reuseNode true
                    image NODE_DOCKER_IMAGE
                    args '-u root'
                }
            }

            steps {
                script {
                    ...
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I edited the file and parallelized stages like so:

```
String NODE_DOCKER_IMAGE = 'company-docker.com:11452/digital-help/node-12-react:latest'

pipeline {
    agent {
        node {
            label 'centos'
        }
    }

    triggers { cron('H 1 * * *') }
    
    stages {
        stage('Prepare') {
            ...
        }

        stage('Install') {
            when {
                beforeAgent true
                not { triggeredBy 'TimerTrigger' }
                not { expression { isSkipCi } }
                not { expression { isReleaseDeployment } }
            }

            agent {
                docker {
                    reuseNode true
                    image NODE_DOCKER_IMAGE
                    args '-u root'
                }
            }

            steps {
                sh 'git clean -dxff'
                sh 'npm ci  --unsafe-perm'
            }
        }

        stage('Tests & Artifacts') {
            when {
                beforeAgent true
                not { triggeredBy 'TimerTrigger' }
                not { expression { isSkipCi } }
            }
            stage('Unit') {
                when { not { expression { isReleaseDeployment } } }
                agent {
                    docker {
                        reuseNode true
                        image NODE_DOCKER_IMAGE
                        args '-u root'
                    }
                }

                steps {
                    sh 'npm run test:unit'
                }

                post {
                    success {
                        step([$class: 'CoberturaPublisher', coberturaReportFile: 'coverage/jest/cobertura-coverage.xml'])
                    }
                }
            }

            stage('Integration') {
                when { not { expression { isReleaseDeployment } } }
                agent {
                    docker {
                        reuseNode true
                        image NODE_DOCKER_IMAGE
                        args '-u root'
                    }
                }

                steps {
                    sh 'npm run test:integration'
                }
            }

            stage('Artifact') {
                agent {
                    docker {
                        reuseNode true
                        image NODE_DOCKER_IMAGE
                        args '-u root'
                    }
                }

                steps {
                    script {
                        ...
                    }
                }
            }        
        }
    }
}
```

All of the stages use the same docker image that `Install` stage added everything it needs during `npm ci` .
Parallel stages take a long time since they are all running same docker image using the same agent, not making it a worthwhile.

Any ideas on how I can improve my parallel execution times?

Comment: The result seems to be what you wanted, as you have requested `reuseNode true`. If you want to run in parallel, you need to create multiple nodes, not reuse the same one.

Comment: I am fumbling through exactly the same issue. Were you able to resolve Jinkes runs to actually run in parallel with the same docker image?